# Mypy: List of Instances? Callables?

Tags: python, python-3.6, mypy

I've started testing mypy on an application, but I don't get success when trying to work with `instances of class`.

`ButtonGenerator.__new__` should accept a List of `BaseButton` (`URLButton`) or simply a `BaseButton` (`URLButton`) instance.

**buttons.py**

```
class BaseButton(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass    

class ButtonGenerator(BaseButton):
    def __new__(self, buttons: Union[List[BaseButton], BaseButton]) -> Union[List[Dict[str, str]], Dict[str, str]]:
        if (isinstance(buttons, list)):
            if (not all(isinstance(button, BaseButton) for button in buttons)):
                raise ValueError('Invalid Buttons instances.')

            return [button.button_dict for button in buttons]

        return buttons.button_dict


class URLButton(BaseButton):
    def __init__(self, url, title=None):
        self.button_dict = {
            'type': 'web_url',
            'url': url
        }

        if (title):
            self.button_dict['title'] = title
```

**Errors**

```
messenger/buttons.py:17: error: "BaseButton" has no attribute "button_dict"
messenger/buttons.py:19: error: "BaseButton" has no attribute "button_dict"
```

Example:
`print(ButtonGenerator(URLButton('https://stackoverflow.com')))`

I tried with List of `Callable` also.

Answer (score 0):

mypy does not currently honor `__new__` if it tries to return a type other than its implicit type:  https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1020

The solution is to use a function or static/classmethod instead.  In your case, I think a function would be *much* more intuitive than a class constructor anyway, since `__new__` is not returning a class at all let along a subclass of `BaseButton`, and this is generally frowned upon. When someone instantiates a class, they expect to get a class instance, not a dictionary or a list.